# AES encryption - password , salt not resolved?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

i get the error " password , salt not resolved ". any suggestions ?

```
package org.temp2.cod1;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Code2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 1024, 256);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal("Hello, World!".getBytes("UTF-8"));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare and initialize the `salt` and `password` variables.

For example, if you pass the password and salt (as a 16-digit hexadecimal number) as the first two arguments to the program when you launch it, it might look like this:

```
char[] password = args[0].toCharArray();
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
  salt[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(args[1].substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);
}
```

Cryptography is extremely difficult in itself. Trying to get familiar with it *and* a new language at the same is only compounding the problem.